# NServiceBus: Load-balancing subscribers

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus-distributor

Is it possible to load balance my subscriber worker nodes without using a distributor?  Here's what I am thinking:

Instead of having my distributor subscribe to a publication, and having each worker node "report for duty" to handle messages, what if I just put each worker node behind a Virtual IP, and subsrcibe this Virtual IP to the publication?  Can you send MSMQ messages to a machine behind a Virtual IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with a "virtual IP" is that you want to have a queue where unprocessed work sits so that you can monitor it, and based on that, increase/decrease the number of worker nodes. Did you run into any problems when using the distributor?

Comment: The distributor seems like a potential bottleneck because all messages for a publication will go to it, and if you end up adding too many subscriptions on the same machine, you may have to partition it in the future (as you mentioned on NSB.com).  For my purposes, I already have monitoring on each MT box and can easily add something for checking queue sizes so I can determine when to add worker nodes.  Load-balancing behind a Virtual IP is what we do every day, and how we manage incremental deployments. Plus I don't like the idea of a "soft" NLB just for the purpose of monitoring.

Comment: BTW, will you be filling in the Monitoring section in the documentation at NServiceBus.com soon?